# Eloquent ORM pagination Reddit-like - before/after hash-id

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I have a table of posts with a rank column. Is there a way to retrieve the previous 20 posts starting from the ID of one post while ordering them by rank. It should behave similarly to reddit's pagination.

Ex. domain.com/posts/previous/{id_of_post_to_start_from}

**UPDATE**

Let me just rephrase this. The normal laravel/eloquent (simple) pagination will use pages and can be achieved by doing something like this:

```
$posts = Post::with(array('user'=>function($q){
            $q->select('id', 'img','nick', 'points', 'slug');
        }))
           ->with('categories')
           ->with('voted')
           ->orderBy('rank', 'DESC')
           ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
           ->simplePaginate(20);
return view('layouts.home')->with('posts',$posts);
```

this will use an url with a `?page=pageNo` argument. Because the ranking changes quite fast, what I really want is to be able to get the following or previous posts after a certain post identified by an id or hashId. This is the way reddit does it:

```
https://www.reddit.com/?count=25&after=t3_4g1n0n
```

**Update 2**

@Jarek's answer seems to be working when ordering by the rank column as it has very few or no duplicates, but it fails when ordering by the number of votes. It only displays 3 pages instead of 5 and in the last one some rows are skipped. I've been trying to solve this for an entire day and I really don't know where to go next. Please help.

My urls are `/ordered-by-votes?before=hashId` and `/ordered-by-votes?after=hashId`

Table structure ordered by `votes desc, created_at desc`:

```
| id  | rank        | votes | url        | created_at          |
+-----+-----------------------------+-----+------------+---------------------+
|  41 | 220.6454978 |  16   | 7X1dqLLNRG | 2016-04-24 08:02:03 |
|  32 | 192.6005579 |  15   | k39djkOGP0 | 2016-04-09 17:49:22 |
|  81 | 401.8382322 |  13   | 7X1dqPLNRG | 2016-07-27 18:04:14 |
|  36 | 192.6460924 |  12   | mZEzDLzxpb | 2016-04-09 19:36:12 |
|  35 | 192.5188647 |   9   | 5ykOxjNBp7 | 2016-04-09 19:34:29 |
|  50 | 325.8341567 |   8   | lm2dpyxOQY | 2016-06-18 06:39:19 |
|  34 | 192.4059869 |   7   | EDMOM0d16m | 2016-04-09 19:31:41 |
|  33 | 192.2031068 |   6   | J6RN0mdGmY | 2016-04-09 17:49:44 |
|  57 | 325.5080990 |   3   | 76mz7R1OGl | 2016-06-18 07:54:15 |
|  56 | 325.5039213 |   3   | KE0NQEkN1p | 2016-06-18 07:51:07 |
|  40 | 193.2540546 |   3   | 796Na28dJr | 2016-04-10 10:43:43 |
|  39 | 193.2262101 |   3   | 6yMNr0Ox-Y | 2016-04-10 10:22:50 |
|  38 | 193.2205435 |   3   | Y21OmeODEp | 2016-04-10 10:18:35 |
|  55 | 325.3238522 |   2   | e4Bd3xoOjg | 2016-06-18 07:48:08 |
|  54 | 325.3145633 |   2   | Z56zRyqOYM | 2016-06-18 07:41:10 |
|  53 | 325.2995633 |   2   | G3JdEMGd0y | 2016-06-18 07:29:55 |
|  52 | 325.2952967 |   2   | gm8dna7Noq | 2016-06-18 07:26:43 |
|  49 | 323.1741856 |   2   | -41zKQndp3 | 2016-06-17 04:55:53 |
|  48 | 323.1371411 |   2   | obmd2DLze2 | 2016-06-17 04:28:06 |
|  47 | 322.2090522 |   2   | 2KGdGR-N9j | 2016-06-16 16:52:02 |
|  45 | 318.4326967 |   2   | ngYN4lRNDB | 2016-06-14 17:39:46 |
|  42 | 244.7367189 |   2   | -arOeX3dby | 2016-05-07 08:27:47 |
|  27 | 191.1572300 |   2   | 7rbzy5zXGm | 2016-04-09 10:43:10 |
|  20 | 183.1333856 |   2   | PE4N13Oa-r | 2016-04-05 06:25:17 |
| 102 | 430.7966222 |   1   | -arOe3mNby | 2016-08-12 09:58:29 |
|  93 | 415.2774667 |   1   | G3JdEjGO0y | 2016-08-04 07:59:07 |
|  80 | 397.8948667 |   1   | 796NaX8zJr | 2016-07-26 06:42:10 |
|  79 | 397.0725111 |   1   | 6yMNrm0zx- | 2016-07-25 20:25:24 |
|  77 | 397.0368667 |   1   | j3-Ob8aN9k | 2016-07-25 19:58:40 |
|  75 | 388.2400889 |   1   | 5ykOxQjzBp | 2016-07-21 06:01:05 |
|  72 | 386.3236889 |   1   | k39djBkdGP | 2016-07-20 06:03:47 |
|  65 | 378.7166889 |   1   | B0kd5bkO7L | 2016-07-16 06:58:32 |
|  64 | 367.0564222 |   1   | l16zlkxOqe | 2016-07-10 05:13:20 |
|  63 | 365.7214000 |   1   | qBEdkk2d2M | 2016-07-09 12:32:04 |
|  62 | 354.0362889 |   1   | Xk3O-1jOEY | 2016-07-03 10:28:14 |
|  61 | 354.0347556 |   1   | kryNP1Kd9a | 2016-07-03 10:27:05 |
|  60 | 353.5897333 |   1   | PE4N123da- | 2016-07-03 04:53:19 |
|  58 | 329.7797111 |   1   | J-azJQ2Oeb | 2016-06-20 19:15:48 |
|  44 | 257.9238889 |   1   | jexdZ0JzR5 | 2016-05-14 09:03:56 |
|  59 | 350.6545778 |   0   | QK2N6yKzn6 | 2016-07-01 16:11:57 |
|  51 | 324.9408000 |   0   | 2P8O8P-Opm | 2016-06-18 06:46:37 |
|  46 | 321.4635111 |   0   | Da8zBj6z-Y | 2016-06-16 11:18:39 |
|  43 | 249.2581556 |   0   | e6XOLJENQ3 | 2016-05-09 20:44:38 |
|  92 | 413.8514933 | -26   | gm8dn07zoq | 2016-08-04 07:50:52 |
```

The `after` method in the model

```
public function scopeAfter($query, self $post)
{
    return $query->orderBy('votes', 'desc')
        ->latest()
        ->where('status', '=', 'approved')
        ->where('id', '<>', $post->id)
        ->where('votes', '<=', $post->votes)
        ->where('created_at', '<=', $post->created_at);
}
```

The controller:

```
$posts=null;
if(isset($req['before'])){
 //...
} elseif (isset($req['after'])){
    $prevPost = Post::where('url','=',$req['after'])->first();
    $posts= Post::after($prevPost)
        ->with('categories', 'voted')
        ->with(array('user'=>function($q){
            $q->select('id', 'img','nick', 'points', 'slug');
        }))
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();
} else {
    // if no params, get the first 10
    $posts= Post::with('categories', 'voted')
        ->with(array('user'=>function($q){
            $q->select('id', 'img','nick', 'points', 'slug');
        }))
        ->where('status','=','approved')
        ->orderBy('votes', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();
}

//return $posts;
```

The view links

```
<a href="{{url('/ordered-by-votes') . '?' . http_build_query(['after' => $lastPost->url])}}" class="btn after">< Previous</a>
<a href="{{url('/ordered-by-votes') . '?' . http_build_query(['before' => $firstPost->url])}}" class="btn before">Before ></a>
```

**Update 3**

There should be 5 pages with 44 results, but only 3 pages and 27 results are displayed.

Page 1 - correct - 10 results

`from 7X1dqLLNRG to KE0NQEkN1p`

Page 2 - correct - 10 results

`from 796Na28dJr to 2KGdGR-N9j`

Page 3 - incorrect - only 7 results are displayed in the wrong order

```
ngYN4lRNDB (OK)
-arOeX3dby (OK)
7rbzy5zXGm (OK)
PE4N13Oa-r (OK)
jexdZ0JzR5 (NOT OK)
Da8zBj6z-Y (NOT OK)
e6XOLJENQ3 (NOT OK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can work with the code:

```
// controller
$post = Post::findByWhateverYouWant($key_from_route);

// higher ranked:
$paginator = Post::before($post)
                 ->with('categories', 'votes')
                 ->simplePaginate(20);

// you need to reverse this result in order to sort 
// appropriately but AFTER the query was executed   
return $paginator->setCollection($paginator->reverse());




// lower ranked:
return Post::after($post)
           ->with('categories', 'votes')
           ->simplePaginate(20);
```

and here's the model with mentioned **scopes**:

```
public function scopeBefore($query, self $post, $sortBy = 'votes')
{
    return $query->orderBy($sortBy)
                 ->orderBy('created_at')
                 ->where('id', '<>', $post->id)
                 ->where(function ($q) use ($post, $sortBy) {
                    $q->where($sortBy, '=', $post->{$sortBy})
                      ->where('created_at', '>=', $post->created_at)
                      ->orWhere($sortBy, '>', $post->{$sortBy});
                 });
}

public function scopeAfter($query, self $post, $sortBy = 'votes')
{
    return $query->orderBy($sortBy, 'desc')
                 ->latest()
                 ->where('id', '<>', $post->id)
                 ->where(function ($q) use ($post, $sortBy) {
                    $q->where($sortBy, '=', $post->{$sortBy})
                      ->where('created_at', '<=', $post->created_at)
                      ->orWhere($sortBy, '<', $post->{$sortBy});
                 });
}
```

<strike>You may add 3rd param to these scopes in order to make `2nd column` customizable if you like.</strike>

Comment: Your solution works beautifully for sets of data with clear, distinct values like the rank column (which is something like 194.0356253) but it fails by not selecting all results or skipping some  when the values are not so distinct. I tried the same method on the votes column (see **Update 2**) and the results were erratic, at best.

Comment: You used `whereDate` for `created_at` timestamp - it's definitely not the same as `where` on timestamp column. Try with simple `where` and if that's not it, then show the result you're getting vs expected, otherwise it's unclear.

Comment: Sorry, it was one of my late night experiments. The results are still the same though. Please see **Update 3** and sorry for all this.

Comment: How about checking the `status=approved` for remaining posts?

Comment: OOOok, got it. gimme 5 min ;)

Comment: Dzięki @Jarek, you're a life saver! I would really like to know why this was happening.

Comment: Because at first the `where` clauses were wrong in that it took only records with **lower** `created_at`, even if `votes` amount was lower. That's why we needed to split it and check `created_at` **only** for those records with the same `votes` amount.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this (you didn't share any code, so put here your model and variables):

```
$perPage = 20;
$toSkip = $id_of_post_to_start_from - $perPage;
$toSkip = $toSkip < 0 ? 0 : $toSkip;
$prevousTwentyPosts = Post::orderBy('rank', 'desc')->skip($toSkip)->take($perPage)->get();
```

to do that:

> Is there a way to retrieve the previous 20 posts starting from the ID
>   of one post while ordering them by rank

Comment: Thanks @Alexey but the IDs are not in order (the rank column is the one that dictates the post order, they're not ordered chronologically) while some others might be missing (deleted posts).

Comment: @Răzvan, sorry, but you didn't post any code and I can't read minds (yet). You can easily adapt my code for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got it right, but can't you just use where('id','>',$id)?

Edit: nvm, you want to paginate through all results so you can't use where.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought you can solve this by turning the current id into a rank, then adding a where clause on rank and finally taking the required number of records.

```
$posts = Post::with(array('user'=>function($q){
            $q->select('id', 'img','nick', 'points', 'slug');
        }))
       ->with('categories')
       ->with('voted')

       ->where('rank', '>', function($q) use ($id){
           $q->select('rank')
             ->from('posts')
             ->where('id', $id);
       })

       ->orderBy('rank', 'DESC')
       ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
       ->take(20);
```